# Defining Fourier transform for non L1 functions

Tags: definition, fourier-transform

in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217739) question, it is explained how one can rigorously define the Fourier transform over $L_1$ functions using a Lebesgue integral. But what about when we transform functions which are *not* in $L_1$?

Specifically, in many branches of physics and engineering it is common to take Fourier transforms of functions such as $cos(t), \space sin(t),\space f(t)=1$

The above examples all result somehow in Dirac Delta functions, which are actually distributions and not functions proper. So it seems we need to come up with a rather different definition of what a Fourier transform is to include these cases.

How can we do this?

Comment: You are asking for description of  an entire theory which is  easily available in books. What sort of answer can one post for this question. You should begin by studying Fourier transforms so $L^{2}$ functions from, say, Rudin's book. Incidentally, this does not involve Dirac delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short a tempered distribution $T$ is uniquely defined by its pairing with gaussians : $$T_{a} = e^{-\pi a^2 x^2} (T \ast \frac1a e^{-\pi x^2/a^2})$$ Note $T_{a}$ is $C^\infty \cap L^1$

(when $a \to 0$, $\frac1a e^{-\pi  x^2/a^2} \to \delta$ and $T \ast \frac1a e^{-\pi  x^2/a^2} \to T$ in the sense of distributions).

Given a tempered distribution, compute the Fourier transform $\hat{T}_{a} = FT[T_a] \in C^\infty \cap L^1$. and let $a \to 0$, you obtain $\hat{T} = \lim_{a \to 0} \hat{T}_a$ (again limit in the sense of distributions) and $\hat{T}_a = \frac1a e^{-\pi x^2/a^2} \ast (e^{-\pi \xi^2 a^2} \hat{T})$, which, if true for one $a$, is true for every $a$.